# Show navigation drawer in large and remove in xlarge

Tags: android

I am developing an android app for tablet in which I got a scenario, where I have to display menu using navigation drawer in large device and in x-large device display menu as layout and no navigation drawer will be there. Can anyone suggest some idea about how to do this?

Comment: Simply set visibility=Gone of your navigation drawer in x-Large device layout file. hope this helps and work well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different layout files for large (contains the nav drawer xml code) and x-large (does not contain the nav drawer xml code) device.

In your java code,

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

if (mDrawerLayout != null) {  
    //Checking for null will make sure that there is no null pointer exception in the x-large screens where there is no nav drawer layout. 
    //Add a similar null check for mDrawerLayout wherever you are using the mDrawerLayout variable. 

    // Setup ActionBar Icon. 
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Set the title on the action when drawer open
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can achieve this using screen size.you have to make different layout for phones and tablet screen.like upto 5.7" devices come into phablet means phone.you have to use layout folder.then come 7 inch tablet for that you have to create a folder  **layout-sw600dp-land** and **layout-sw600dp-port** for landscape and portrait mode respectivily. same is for 10 inch device you have to create  a folder  **layout-sw720dp-land** and **layout-sw720dp-port** for landscape and portrait mode respectivily. **THIS** is all about Xml design for layout.

## now on activity:

check the device size on splash screen (if it is in your project else use this code begore set content view)and convert that into inch like below i am doing:

```
try {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int displayHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int displayWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        double x = Math.pow(displaymetrics.widthPixels
                / displaymetrics.xdpi, 2);
        double y = Math.pow(displaymetrics.heightPixels
                / displaymetrics.ydpi, 2);
        double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
        Log.d("debug", "Screen inches : " + screenInches);
        int _deviceinch = (int) (screenInches);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and check the device size and set the contentview for your device like:

```
if (a <= 6) {
        setContentView(R.layout.phone_all_products);
    } else if (a >= 7 && a < 9) {
        setContentView( R.layout.seven_inch_all_products);
                 System.out.println("in seven inch");
    } else if (a >= 9) {
        setContentView(R.layout.ten_inch_all_products);
        System.out.println("in ten inch");
    }
```